# Round Pandas date to nearest year/month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to round a pandas datetime column to its nearest year or month but I cannot figure out how to do it. For instance, this minimal example rounds to the closest hour:

```py
pd.Timestamp.now().round('60min')
```

What I'd like is a way to replace the `'60min'` in order to round `pd.Timestamp.now()` to obtain either `2020-01-01` (for the year case) or `2019-08-01` (for the month case) (note that `now()` is exactly `2019-07-30 16:41:23.612004` at the time of asking!).

The [pandas.Series.dt.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) doc suggest a `freq` argument linking to [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases), but trying the months/years options there return this error:

```py
ValueError:  is a non-fixed frequency
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: This is an open issue in pandas right now: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303

Answer (score 3):

If the column is really DateTime column (check with `df.dtypes`), you can get the year, month & day with the code below.

```
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day

df['round_Year'] = df['Date']+ pd.offsets.YearBegin(-1)
```

rounds off to start of current year. Change -1 to 0 rounds off to start of next year.

```
df['round_Month'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)
```

rounds off to start of current Month. Change -1 to 0 rounds off to start of next Month

Comment: not clear what you want. can you put the data you have and the output you desire.

Comment: `dff['round_Year'] = dff['Date']+ pd.offsets.YearBegin(-1)` rounds off to start of current year. Change -1 to 0 rounds off to start of next year
`dff['round_Month'] = dff['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)` rounds off to start of current Month. Change -1 to 0 rounds off to start of next Month

Comment: Thanks mohanys, that partly solves my problem. To me this behaviour is closer to floor/ceil than a proper round function though, but I guess I get why from the pandas issue raised by maow.

Answer (score 0):

Example of rounding a Python [Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) to the nearest half year:

```
from Pandas import Timestamp

def round_date_to_nearest_half_year(ts: Timestamp) -> Timestamp:
    if 4 <= ts.month <=8:
        return Timestamp(ts.year, 7, 1)
    elif ts.month >=9:
        return Timestamp(ts.year+1, 1, 1)
    elif ts.month <= 3:
        return Timestamp(ts.year, 1, 1)
    else:
        raise Exception("Logic error.")
```

Test:

```
print(round_date_to_nearest_half_year(Timestamp("2022-6-5")))
print(round_date_to_nearest_half_year(Timestamp("2022-7-3")))
print(round_date_to_nearest_half_year(Timestamp("2022-12-15")))
print(round_date_to_nearest_half_year(Timestamp("2023-1-5")))
```

Out:

```
2022-07-01 00:00:00
2022-07-01 00:00:00
2023-01-01 00:00:00
2023-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a variable date_ts which is a date in a Timestamp format:

```
Timestamp('1939-01-29 00:00:00')
```

And you want to get date_ts_rounded, the rounded date to the nearest month in a Timestamp format :

```
Timestamp('1939-01-01 00:00:00')
```

All you have to do is :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_ts_month_year = pd.Timestamp(f"{date_ts.month}/{date_ts.year}")
date_ts_rounded = pd.Timestamp(date_ts_month_year).normalize()
```

Hope this helps.